# How to put a criteria for the function in a query?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a query where one of the fields is a function I wrote to get the due dates for trainings.

The function works and when I run my query it gives the correct dates but when I try to put in a criteria in the query to for example only output the due dates that are <31 days it gives me the error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

This is in the field for the query:

```
Due Date: getDueDate([Workday_Excel_Update].[Course Number])
```

This is the function:

```vb
Function getDueDate(CourseNum As String)

Dim yearCounter As Integer
Dim yearStart As Date
Dim yearNow As Integer
Dim monthFreq As Integer
Dim daysDue As Integer

'check if course number is part of the tracked trainings
If Not IsNull(DLookup("CourseName", "CourseNumbers", "CourseNumber = '" & CourseNum & "'")) Then

    'if it is part of tracked training calculate date
    monthFreq = DLookup("[Months]", "CourseNumbers", "CourseNumber = '" & CourseNum & "'")
    yearStart = DLookup("[Frequency]", "CourseNumbers", "CourseNumber = '" & CourseNum & "'")
    yearCounter = Year(yearStart)
    yearNow = Year(Date)

    While yearCounter < yearNow
        yearStart = DateAdd("m", monthFreq, yearStart)
        yearCounter = yearCounter + (monthFreq / 12)
    Wend

    daysDue = CInt(DateDiff("d", Date, yearStart))

'Else
    'daysDue = 0

End If

getDueDate = daysDue

End Function
```

Example data:

CourseNumbers (Table)

| CourseNumber | CourseName | Frequency | Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1234-training | 1900-12-31 | 12 |

Workday_Excel_Update (Linked Table)

| User ID | Badge ID | First Name | Last Name | Email Address | Primary Supervisor | Completion Date | Course Title | Course Number | Lesson Completion Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0022334455 | 54321 | Frank | Smith | frank.smith@work.com | John Leblanc | 2021-05-20 2:59:54 PM | 11234-training | 1234 | Not Started |

SQL code of the Query:

```
SELECT Workday_Excel_Update.[User ID], Workday_Excel_Update.[Badge ID], Workday_Excel_Update.[First Name], Workday_Excel_Update.[Last Name], Workday_Excel_Update.[Email Address], Workday_Excel_Update.[Primary Supervisor], Workday_Excel_Update.[Completion Date], (getDueDate([Workday_Excel_Update].[Course Number])) AS [Days Until Due Date], Workday_Excel_Update.[Course Title], Workday_Excel_Update.[Lesson Completion Status]
FROM CourseNumbers INNER JOIN Workday_Excel_Update ON CourseNumbers.CourseNumber = Workday_Excel_Update.[Course Number]
WHERE (((Workday_Excel_Update.[Lesson Completion Status])<>"Completed" Or (Workday_Excel_Update.[Lesson Completion Status]) Is Null))
ORDER BY (getDueDate([Workday_Excel_Update].[Course Number]));
```

The getDueDate() function in the query will take as input a course number from another table which has a registration date for each employee. The registration date goes through a DateDiff() with the calculated due date and outputs an integer indicating the number of days left until the training is due or the number of days past the due date.

Query criteria
[image: Image of query criteria I'm trying to get]

I also get the following error when I try to filter the query
[image: I also get the following error when I try to filter the query]

Comment: If there is no return from the 1st dlookup you get a 0 return of integer type, not a date.  also `[Due Date]` or `Due_Date` may be TBH not quite sure what you are asking

Comment: I added an image. When I give the query a criteria it gives me the error I stated above but when there is no criteria the query works and outputs all. I just want to put in a criteria so that it only outputs the due dates that are coming up in under 30 days.

Comment: Try explicitly declaring the function return type, i.e. `Function getDueDate(CourseNum As String) As Integer `

Comment: I have no problem using criteria with a field calculated by a function, even without type declaration. Something is not right about function logic - have you step debugged? `Frequency` is a date/time field? `GetDueDate` appears to be a misleading name - the function does not get a date, it gets an integer. Edit question to show sample data as a text table.

Comment: I already tried declaring the return type but it doesn't change anything @Sam

Comment: I edited the question with more detail @June7

Comment: Should always post full SQL statement as well as error message as text instead of images that have to be opened and/or may be difficult to read. I will do some testing. Seems odd that Frequency is a date value - is it actually a date/time field? `Month` is a reserved word and really should avoid reserved words as names.

Comment: You say the registration date gets compared - where? In the function? I am not seeing a registration date pulled. You should edit question to show sample of all relevant data as text tables. Why is Frequency a date value of year 1900? My testing is stalled.

Comment: @June7 I edited the question with the information you needed. I put example data for both tables in the query and I also added the SQL code for the query. As for the comparison I explained it in the question as well. Basically it's more of an arithmetic equation where I use the DateDiff() function to find the amount of days left between the registration date and the calculated due date which is then outputted in the query. Hope this helps.

Comment: @June7 also I can't change the year from 1900 because that is the data given to me to work with so in my getDueDate() function all I did was add the corresponding Months to the frequency until it is greater or equal to the present year. After that I go through the DateDiff().

Comment: Okay, tested with <31 criteria - data, query, code as you posted. Works, no error, record retrieved. Why would record have a completion date with a "Not started" status?

Comment: Did you change anything to make it work? Because I am getting the error when I use the criteria but no error without the criteria. It's not a the "Completion Date " it's the "Lesson Completion Status" that has the "Not Started" status.